# flutter Xcode can't run

Tags: xcode, flutter

I just need to open a project sent to me 
using flutter I am running on a mac pc and I am asked to run it on Xcode 
so i tried and every time the same error appear
the last error I didn't find any solve for it on the internet

```
[abdelrhmans-MacBook-Pro:anjez-master softa$ flutter build ios
Building com.AnjezApplication for device (ios-release)...

Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: B26V682XJP
Running Xcode build...                                                  

Xcode build done.                                            5.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2020-04-27 17:16:15.629 XCBBuildService[9613:172921] Failed to remove:
    /Users/softa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ciptqvveswepfdfwscmmoplxkvyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/5f0231a6e51d06ee16e07b566b453277-desc.xcbuild:
    unlink(/Users/softa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ciptqvveswepfdfwscmmoplxkvyx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/5f0231a6e51d06ee16e07b566b453277-desc.xcbuild): No such file or directory (2)
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/softa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/phone_number-0.3.1/ios/Classes/SwiftPhoneNumberPlugin.swift:41:11: warning: 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block
            } catch {
              ^
    /Users/softa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/phone_number-0.3.1/ios/Classes/SwiftPhoneNumberPlugin.swift:41:11: warning: 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block
            } catch {
              ^
    /Users/softa/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/phone_number-0.3.1/ios/Classes/PhoneNumberPlugin.m:2:9: fatal error: 'phone_number/phone_number-Swift.h' file not found
    #import <phone_number/phone_number-Swift.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')

Encountered error while building for device.
abdelrhmans-MacBook-Pro:anjez-master softa$ flutter run

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              4.0s
Running Xcode build...                                                  

Xcode build done.                                            4.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.4.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    error: Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'App.framework' was built for iOS. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (2nd generation).
]
```

Here is a photo representation of the error : 
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twJWA.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean the project with the `flutter clean` command.

Comment: i will add the pics in post

Comment: i shared my pubspec.yaml in comment

Comment: hello, can you try a pod desintegrate in ios folder, `pod desintegrate` and build again please